# Laravel withCount, dont count comment if parent comment user is inactive

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, lumen

I came across a weird problem that i cant find the answer how to resolve.

For example i have commenting system on a social network site, which has unlimited level replies to parent comment on a status or picture or whatever.

So i am counting replies with **$q->withCount('replies');**
I have a globalScope which check if user is inactive (active 1 or 0). It works perfectly with not showing inactive user comment and his child subcomments, but it does count wrong total number of replies.

Example code:

```
$discourse = RockChat::with([
    "getAuthor",
    "isLiked",
    "lastReply",
    "category"    => function ($q) {
        $q->addSelect("name", "id");
    },
    "subcategory" => function ($q) {
        $q->addSelect("name", "id");
    },
    "replies" => function ($q) {
        $q->withCount("likes");
        $q->with(["isLiked", "replies" => function ($q) {
            $q->withCount("likes");
            $q->with(["isLiked"]);
        }]);
    }])
    ->withCount("replyNumber")
    ->withCount("likes")
    ->where("category_id", $request->get("category"))
    ->where("subcategory_id", $request->get("subcategory"))
    ->where("slug", $request->get("id"))
    ->first();
```

and a globalScope

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('user_active', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->whereHas('getAuthor');
    });
}
```

I quite cant figure out, how to check if parent comment user is inactive, so dount count child replies as total of replies to status or picture comments or whatever.

I tried applyin global scope to withCount relation method.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the SQL it's generating and the SQL you need it to generate. You will probably have to add the condition again via a join to the parent